# Running with Virtual Box

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox

I recently purchased a new laptop and I am currently dual booting windows 7 and the latest Ubuntu package, my question is there a way that i can run that my Ubuntu in Virtual box? Until now i've only been using iso images and i looking for a solution or some one point to point me the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To **install** Ubuntu in Virtual Box see http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox to run an already installed Ubuntu in Virtual Box see http://askubuntu.com/questions/78902/cannot-run-native-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-with-a-vmdk-created-using-the-createrawvm

Answer (score 0):

you can run Ubuntu in a virtual box but dual booting is much preferred as it gives a full desktop experience 
anyway, if you decide to run it in virtual box then you need virtual box(obviously), a minimum of 20 gig of free space,latest Ubuntu iso(download it from the official site or a torrent 32bit preferable as you are installing it virtually but if you have a lot of ram go on and grab a 64bit  ) and a minimum of 2 gb ram on the host i.e your windows
now open the virtual box
 click new > give a name > select ubuntu from drop down menu > select ram of 700mb or more but not more than the half of actual size of your ram > next > select create new virtual hard drive or disk> vdi > dynamic > 20gig > create
now you'll see ubuntu or whatever name you gave on the panel,select it 
select settings > storage select controller ide select empty and on the right side you'll find a small cd icon click the cd icon and select "choose a virtual cd disk"
and navigate to the place where you downloaded the iso 
select the iso and click ok and ok again in settings window now you'll be at the beginning of the virtual box select start and follow the instructins on screen